# Mongoid: embedded documents automatically initializing on construction of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, initialization, mongoid, embedded-database

Is there a way to get embedded documents to initialize automatically on construction in mongoid?  What I mean is given that User which embeds a garage document.  I have to write the following code to fully set up the user with the garage:

```
user = User.create!(name: "John")
user.build_garage
user.garage.cars << Car.create!(name: "Bessy")
```

Is there a way I can skip calling `user.build_garage`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a callback to the User model like this:

```
class User
  ...
  after_initialize do |u|
    u.build_garage unless u.garage
  end
  ...
end
```

This callback fires after each instantiation of the class, so it fires after 'find' and 'new'.

Comment: Is firing after find a good idea because doesn't that mean it will overwrite the previous embedded document?

Comment: Are there any mongoid autos that do this for the user?

Comment: I edited the answer to fix your first point. No, there are no automatisms for that. I would say that such functionality belongs to the actual application code.

Comment: Dude. You rock! I was trying to use the initialize method to do this. Even though I was calling super first, the condition was failing and adding an extra doc. 

I'd add that maybe you should add a garage.exists? to that unless

Comment: Mongoid 3 now has an option for this, [autobuild](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/1188)

Answer (score 12):

Mongoid 3 have `autobuild` option which tells Mongoid to instantiate a new document when the relation is accessed and it is `nil`.

```
embeds_one :label, autobuild: true
has_one :producer, autobuild: true
```